# Why does DbSet Add return an entity instance instead of void?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

The [DbSet<TEntity>.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679587%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method returns an entity.  I would normally have expected an `Add` operation to have a `void` return type.

When I look at the [EntityFramework source code](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest), I see the following implementation:

```
    public virtual TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        Check.NotNull(entity, "entity");

        GetInternalSetWithCheck("Add").Add(entity);
        return entity;
    }
```

`GetInternalSetWithCheck` returns an `InternalSet<TEntity>`

The `Add` method of `InternalSet<TEntity>` interestingly enough has a void return type in its signature:

```
public virtual void Add(object entity)
```

My concern is whether or not I need to be careful with when I do modifications to an entity with relation to when it is added to a DbSet.

E.g. are there cases where

```
var entity = new MyEntity();
_dbSet.Add(entity);
entity.SomeDatModifyingMethod();
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

might give different behavior than

```
var entity = new MyEntity();
entity.SomeDatModifyingMethod();
_dbSet.Add(entity);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

or different behavior than:

```
var entity = new MyEntity();
entity = _dbSet.Add(entity);
entity.SomeDatModifyingMethod();
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

In the basic default implementation, it wouldn't ever matter, because it just always returns exactly the same instance. However, the `Add` method is `virtual`, so it can be overridden (though in the public source code, the only override is a test double - but I'm not sure that source code actually includes e.g. the SqlServer support implementation).

Why does DbSet Add return an entity instance instead of void?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TEntity` is a reference type, so what gets added to the `InternalSet<T>` will be a *reference* to the entity, not the value. It doesn't matter whether you change the contents of the entity before or after it is added to the set, since it has never been created in the database. One way or another, an `INSERT` or the equivalent will be performed.

As to why `Add` returns `TEntity`, it expect it's because it permits things like:

```
_dbSet.Add(new MyEntity()).SomeDatModifyingMethod();
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: That mostly makes sense - so long as the `Add` method will never do something like return a proxy - perhaps for change tracking? - in which case it might be important to reassign the reference after adding? (e.g. last code sample)

Comment: Though come to think of it, I don't know why you'd ever need change tracking an a newly added entity...

Comment: The `Add` might not be the last change before the `SaveChanges`. What if there's a `Remove`?

Comment: Sorry, when I said it wouldn't need change tracking for an added entity, I meant that it wouldn't need to track the added entity other than for the fact that it is added - meaning that even if you are using EF proxy change tracking, there doesn't seem to be a reason that Add would need to "proxify" the added entity (to track individual property changes) - thus lending credence to your statement that returning the entity is simply for method chaining.

Answer (score 8):

It allows you to write a "Find or Add" pattern

```
var person = context.People.Find(ssn) ?? context.People.Add(new Person
{
   SocialSecurityNumber = ssn,
   FirstName = "John",
   LastName = "Doe"
});
```